# Try/catch all block in C++ program not working

Tags: c++

Try/catch block in C++ not being "caught."
I'm trying to have one catch block to get all exceptions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  try
  {
    throw 1;
  }
  catch (exception& e)
  {
    cout << "ERROR: " << e.what() << endl;

    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You threw an `int`, not a `std::exception`. To catch 'all', `catch(...)`.

Comment: Is it possible to then get info about what kind of exception it was if I use ... ?

Comment: @Gary no, it is not

Comment: Do you want to know the *type* of the exception (e.g. `int`) or the *value* (e.g. `1`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`throw 1;` will throw an `int`. As you do not catch an `int`, the exception goes uncaught, which is undefined behavior.  Though it is possible to throw anything, always prefer to throw a class that derives from `std::exception`.  You *can* catch an `int` with `catch(int e)` or `catch(...)`, but there's really no reason to ever do that.

If you catch with `catch(...)`, then you do not know the type of the object, so cannot access any members, properties, or other aspects, and so you cannot* gather *any* information about what was thrown. This should never be used.

*There *are* ways to get information about the thrown object, but it's far easier to just catch the right type in the first place

Comment: Thank you, good info. If I use "..." am I able to determine what caused the error? What I'm trying to do is catch runtime errors I didn't catch.

Comment: @Gary: Then the right thing to do is throw a `std::runtime_exception`.  With `catch(...)` it is impossible to determine what caused the error.

Comment: *"the exception goes uncaught, which is undefined behavior"* - No, it's pretty well defined as calling `std::terminate`.

Comment: @MooingDuck "*the right thing to do is throw a `std::runtime_exception`*" - you mean [std::runtime_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) instead

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing an `int`, but only catching `std::exception`. Use a `catch(...)` to catch everything thrown.